# how to change the value of the input field of the bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am new to js,ajax and jquery, i am trying to update the value of the input field of the bootstrap modal but this code isn't working,please take a look and suggest the changes

html/-
(have to change the value of id="expt1" & "expt2")

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">USER DETAILS</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          <input id="expt1" type="text" placeholder="enter something">
          <input id="expt2"  type="text" placeholder="enter something else">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

ajax/-

```
function myfunction(name){
       $.ajax({
            url:"showStudents.php",
            type: "post", 
            data: {
                registration: "success", 
                name: name
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(obj);
                $("#name").text(data);
                var tr = "<tr><td>1.</td><td>"+obj[0]+"</td><td>"+obj[1]+"</td></tr>";
                $("#something").html(tr);
                document.getElementById("expt1").value=obj[0];
         });
```

i've not shown how and where the myfunction(name) is being called,but it's being called, after clicking the submit button(which again is not showed here),and ajax is useed to display a table row with data being retrieved from database(working fine but value of id=expt1 is not being changed).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but since you are using jQuery, try using jQuery function to update the value i.e: $("#expt1").val(obj[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `jquery`

**Try this**

```
$('#expt1').val('') //input the value inside of val(yourvalue)
```